# Two devices + one antenna

Tags: repeater, antenna-system

What I have:

- GSM 900 repeater
- 900 - 2400 MHz MIMO antenna 2xSMA
- MIMO 4G Router works with 1800 MHz LTE

Is it a good idea to connect GSM repeater via SMA splitter to one of the antenna cables? Will the devices interfere with each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways to “split” a coaxial connection, and some of them are wrong.

- The simplest, cheapest thing you would find in SMA form factor is a *tee,* a small device with 3 SMA (or other coaxial) connectors. **You should not use this** because it will allow the transmission of one device into the receiver of the other, possibly damaging it with the high power. Also a tee used without care creates an impedance mismatch. Correct uses of a tee are either carefully-measured cases like matching stubs, connecting high-input-impedance test gear such as an oscilloscope, or very low-frequency applications where transmission line length is unimportant.
- You could use a *power divider* (or combiner, it's the same thing) — this is the same type of device as used to connect multiple TVs to one cable-TV or antenna cable. This will work in principle but the devices may interfere with each other, and the incoming signal will be reduced by 3 dB.
- The best solution in this case, where the two devices are widely separated in frequency, is known as a **diplexer** or **duplexer**. It has three ports, one which you would connect to the antenna and two more which are frequency-specific. You would choose a diplexer whose lower-frequency range includes 900 MHz and whose higher-frequency range includes 1800 MHz.

  Because the diplexer contains filters, it will reduce interference between the two devices (if any). In fact, it *might* be even better than using separate antennas — but it depends a lot on the characteristics and quality of the devices' receivers and transmitters whether there will be a problem at all in either case.

Comment: I think the more significant reason to not use a T is the transmitter of one device will overload and perhaps permanently damage the receiver on the other device.

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II Good point; added. I was thinking of the general reason not to use tees and forgot the more-important specific one.

Comment: No concerns using a diplexer when one frequency is the second harmonic of the other?

Comment: @GlennW9IQ I don't know — got a reference to learn more? (I also wouldn't be surprised if the actual frequencies are less round numbers than were given.)