# Can I make a simple Tx/Rx antenna (Radio System) which will receive signal from BTS and broadcast/transmit it, and vice versa?

Tags: antenna, transceiver, transmitter, transmission

Consider a situation as below. I am stay in a farm field, which my house is 9.4km distance from the nearest and the only one BTS (Base Transceiver System), a cellular antenna for transmit and receive signal of 2G/3G network. Measurement I did using Google. In between my house and the BTS, there is hill which block direct signal to the house. If I climb to a three near my house around 8 meter high, I will get signal around 93dBm (up and down). Then I think to make an outdoor parabolic antenna which will be connected by a coax cable to an indoor omni antenna which will serve 360 degree inside the house 5 meter radius. The diagram is as in the picture below. The outdoor antenna itself will compensate the cable loss plus will give more gain. I expect I will get around 90 dBm signal strength after installing the antenna. For now, forget about the antenna detail.

To get the signal in the house, I probably need an electronic device located in between outdoor (parabolic) and indoor (omni) antenna. That device is intended to receive that signal from outdoor and send to indoor without any modification or amplification, just to make the indoor antenna will radiate signal. And vice versa also will do, to send the received signal from indoor and delivered to the outdoor antenna and radiate to send it to the BTS.

Then,

- How can I do it? I need as simple as possible electronic device.
- Or, can I do it without any electronic (active) device?

**Edit:** What is done in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHWrRG_kdn8) is almost the same to my intention. This video makes an external Yagi antenna and attached to the back side of the phone. But I also don't how how it work. There supposed to be there is "transformation" or induction (?) so there is electric transfer from the coax-cable to the antenna. *Then, is any one here can guide me to do that way?*

[image: schematic diagram]

Comment: Please explain what BTS is.

Comment: Don't you know BTS? It is cellular network. Base Transceiver System.

Comment: I do now, but please note that *this is primarily an amateur radio website*, and you seem to be asking about commercial radio.

Comment: What is mean commercial radio? Do you understand my question? I don't even ask any radio there.

Comment: Amateur radio is a hobby, not-for-profit service. Commercial radio means for-profit. I think perhaps that you should first understand the definition of [Amateur Radio](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_radio). ;-)

Comment: http://www.arrl.org/what-is-ham-radio

Comment: No, your understanding to my question is wrong. If you think that only HAM radio we can ask here, then question about GPS supposed to be wrong. So do Wi-Fi. Even some also asked about cellular antenna. The ting is, not about industry. In my question, I just ask how can I reach signal when my position is blocked by an obstacle (hill) in this case. I clearly stated **_without any modification or amplification_**. Mean, there is no requirement to make modulation/demodulation. I suggest you better improve your knowledge.

Comment: What Mike is saying, is that this is an amateur radio site, but that questions about the technology of radio are also welcome here. However, if you use jargon terms or abbreviations for anything that is outside of the field of amateur radio, you will need to clarify what those are in order for people to understand. I know of two abbreviations BTS (one is a K-pop band, the other is the mass-transit system in Bangkok where I live), and also was confused when I read your question.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but you are trying to make something like [this](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/9244/two-devices-one-antenna)? Right?

Comment: What is such different with amateur radio? Still using antenna, capacitor, inductor, feeder line, and the most important, feeder line, right? Unless I asked about cellular modulation, and so on. I clearly said in the last sentence in the first paragraph: **_"For now, forget about the antenna detail."_** My question how to make a received signal from one antenna and pass it to another antenna without any changing. That's the whole problem, the whole question. How to do it. Preferred if without any device. That mean, if any other way, like do induction, etc.

Comment: @DuckDodgers, not it is not. What I want is closer to what is shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHWrRG_kdn8). Unfortunately, no detail how it work. Need guide how to make the part that is attached to the back side of the phone. That one also will do.

Comment: @Sitorus I cannot understand what you are asking.  You clearly state what you intend to do, but it appears to have nothing to do with the video you linked to.  It sounds like you do not know how to attach the plate to the phone; if so, please clearly state that.  Also, PLEASE edit your question to define BTS (not just in comments).  FYI, there are many cell-related questions already here; this will likely be closed as being a duplicate but it is not yet clear which existing question is being duplicated :-)

Comment: @ChrisK8NVH, As in the video, he made an external Yagi Antenna to receive signal, connected a coax cable to it. And the end of the cable is put to the back of the phone. And he claimed the signal is better after the external antenna. That almost solve my question. But that way has limitation as not free to move. What I want is another end is connected to another antenna which will transmit power to the mobile phone.

Comment: Sounds like you need a cell phone extender.  These are commercial devices you can buy for a reasonable amount from common vendors, sold for enhancing cell signals in partially blocked locations.  Mount it on a pole 8-10 m up, in a weather tight enclosure, and good to go.

Comment: @tomnexus, seems interesting. Let me finish to read very carefully.

Comment: @ZeissIkon, I heard such device few years ago. But no more sold like that as most buildings are now covers with indoor antenna. But vendor clearly doesn't sold it. It was illegal to use it, but still many use when signal was not so good enough. But now no more sell that kind of device. Then, I have to make my self. If you don't mind, can you please comment how [this way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHWrRG_kdn8) work? He put one end on the back of his phone, and he claimed it improved lot of the signal strength.

Comment: I see, the ones I find now are several hundred dollars and offered by cell providers.  Legal, I'm certain, but costly up front.

Comment: @tomnexus, how does the system work? How the directional antenna (24dBi) receive signal and the omni-directional antenna will transmit the received signal by the directional antenna without any active device in between?

Comment: @ZeissIkon, rule in our country is, other than 2.4GHz and 5.6GHz (if I am not mistaken) which are public, plus military, are licensed. So, no single person or party can use that frequency if not pay. And, using a device to generate frequency is consider breaching the government rule. That's the reason the operator will not sell it as they also will be fined by government for such breaching rule.

Comment: The cell provider must already have a license for those frequencies; it wouldn't be a violation for them to sell you an extender, any more than it's a violation for them to sell you a cell phone.